# Advice for MySQL schema design that supports filtering on common attributes of disparate types?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema, hierarchy, class-table-inheritance

I would like to represent the following **type system** (this is a hierarchical type system, NOT hierarchical data) in MySQL:

```
type A {
  id
  name
}

type B extends A {
  id
  name
  color
}

type C extends A {
  id
  name
  shape
}
```

which is represented by an inheritance tree as follows:

```
     A
   /   \
  B     C
```

**Essentially, I would like to store a set of objects of types `B` and `C` (the "leaf" types) in my MySQL Database.** I would also want to run each of the example queries below over my set of objects:

1. Get objects of type `A` where `name` starts with `tetra` SORT BY
   `name` offset 0 limit 10
2. Get objects of type `B` where `color` is `blue` SORT BY `name`
   offset 10 limit 10
3. Get objects of type `C` where `shape` is `square` SORT BY `id` limit 10

**I was wondering what the best MySQL schema would be to satisfy these requirements?**

---

Here's my current approach, although I'm somewhat hesitant to move forward as it requires significant de-normalization:

```
// global "reference" table containing all fields
// you can filter or sort by
table Objects {
  id (required) 
  name (required)
  color (optional)
}

table ObjectsOfTypeB {
  id (required)
  name (required)
  color (required)
}

table ObjectsOfTypeC {
  id (required)
  name (required)
  shape (optional)
}
```

So for any of the above queries, we would refer to the `Objects` table to perform filtering / sorting / pagination. Then we could return the resulting `id`s and resolve those `id`s in the individual ObjectOfType tables. The downside here is that we have to keep the "reference" table in-sync with all the individual type tables, and we are duplicating data storage.

Alternatively, I also thought about running multiple separate queries and then joining them in-memory. Taking query #1 (Get objects of type `A` where `name` starts with `tetra` SORT BY `name` offset 0 limit 10) as an example, the approach would be:

1. Get objects of type `B` where `name` starts with `tetra` SORT BY `name` limit 10
2. Get objects of type `C` where `name` starts with `tetra` SORT BY `name` limit 10
3. Merge the results and return the first 10. Return a complex cursor that records how many elements we took from each of B and C that can be used for subsequent pagination.

One downside of this approach is that pagination here could become very complicated and add additional work for MySQL, especially if the type system were to have high "fan-out".

Any tips on this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4048151/3404097)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Google your title. But books have been written.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: @philipxy - Thanks, I have read all the resources to which you have linked. The question I am asking is actually quite different. I am not really storing hierarchical data (i.e., there are no "parent" / "children" nodes). Rather, the data is simply hierarchical in its type structure.

I was somewhat concerned with the title that it might be confused with the more common "Nested set model" question, so I agree I could do better to clarify there. However, if you read the details (which are admittedly long), you will see that the question is indeed quite different.

Comment: That link is one more oriented towards fixed or arbitrary level  tree-structured relation(ship)s but dealing with type heirarchies is still an easily found faq. I'll follow this by my generic comment on that. "parent-child" is a generic term meaning that a relationship has transitive aspects & the use or non-use of the terms tells you nothing by itself. Moreover the same designs are applicable to both applications but you need to explore applying them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097) Re "research" in [ask]: Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the advice @philipxy. Will certainly spend more time searching prior to asking in the future.

Comment: Take a look at "Class Table Inheritance", as a tag here in Stackoverflow, and also in many articles on the web.  Your solution resembles class table inheritance,  except that you might want to make ObjectsoftypeB.id and ObjectsoftypeC.id be foreign keys that reference Objects.Id in addition to beingthe primary key in their own table.